# powershell drives calculator

Tags: powershell, drives

So I have the below code which works quite well but for some reason it's only calculating my D: drive and not also my C: drive?

```
$computerName = Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = Get-Wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem
$computerHDD = Get-Wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

ForEach($HDD in $computerHDD){
$txtObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'ComputerName' = $computerName.Name
    'ComputerModel' = $computerName.Model
    'SerialNumber' = $computerName.SerialNumber
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($HDD.Size/1GB)
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($HDD.FreeSpace/$HDD.Size)
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption
    'OS_type' = $computerOS.OSArchitecture
    'User' = $computerName.UserName
    } 
}
$txtObject | Select-Object ComputerName, ComputerModel, SerialNumber, HDDSize, HDDFree, OS, Os_type, User | Out-File "$PSSCriptRoot\computer_info.txt" -Append
```

Comment: Is your `D:` drive a drive of type `3` (local disk)?  Not a removable disk (`2`) or compact disc (`5`)?

Comment: My D: drive is a mechanical hard drive and my C: drive is an SSD.

Comment: Sorry, I read that backwards; so it's _only_ calculating the `D:` drive.  Anyways, this all hinges on what gets stored in`$computerHDD`.  If `Get-Wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk` is not returning all of the drives you're expecting it to then they'll never get processed in the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: That's correct I get: HDDSize       : 465.66
HDDFree       : 37.71%

Comment: Find out your SSD drive type with `Get-CimInstance  Win32_LogicalDisk`.

Comment: DeviceID DriveType ProviderName VolumeName Size         FreeSpace
-------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----         ---------
C:       3                                 249480343552 120315674624
D:       3                                 500000878592 188527419392
E:       5                      COJ_START  4687134720   0

Comment: I think it's because you're overwriting `$txtObject` on every iteration of the loop when you should be appending to it (as an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you would need to make an array. Try this...

```
$computerName = Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = Get-Wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem
$computerHDD = Get-Wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

$output = @()
ForEach($HDD in $computerHDD){
$txtObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'ComputerName' = $computerName.Name
    'ComputerModel' = $computerName.Model
    'SerialNumber' = $computerName.SerialNumber
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($HDD.Size/1GB)
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($HDD.FreeSpace/$HDD.Size)
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption
    'OS_type' = $computerOS.OSArchitecture
    'User' = $computerName.UserName
    } 
    $output += $txtObject
}
$output | Select-Object ComputerName, ComputerModel, SerialNumber, HDDSize, HDDFree, OS, Os_type, User | Out-File "$PSSCriptRoot\computer_info.txt" -Append
```

Comment: Thanks that works quite well. Only small niggle is that it produces two similar lists, difference being the SSD/HDD.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the labels?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `$txtObject` on every iteration of the loop, so your output only contains the drive from the final iteration.  Instead, you should be initializing `$txtObject` as an array and then appending each drive's information to that:

```
$computerHDD = Get-Wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

$txtObject = @()
ForEach($HDD in $computerHDD){
    $txtObject += New-Object PSObject -property @{
        # ...
    } 
}
$txtObject | Select-Object ... | Out-File "$PSSCriptRoot\computer_info.txt" -Append
```

Better yet, you can eliminate the loop and the variable and just use the pipeline:

```
$computerName = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem

Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3 `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'ComputerName'  = $computerName.Name
            'ComputerModel' = $computerName.Model
            'SerialNumber'  = $computerName.SerialNumber
            'HDDSize'       = "{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)
            'HDDFree'       = "{0:P2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size)
            'OS'            = $computerOS.caption
            'OS_type'       = $computerOS.OSArchitecture
            'User'          = $computerName.UserName
        };
    } | Out-File "$PSSCriptRoot\computer_info.txt" -Append
```

Note that `New-Object` above is nearly identical to your original code except `$_` has to be used instead of `$HDD`.